# How to control ASP.NET request timeouts here in 2013?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

We have some specific web pages and Web Api services which call long-running back end processes; and we'd like to carefully control when they should timeout.

I have created a simple MVC 4 site (in VS2012) with a page that sleeps for 200 seconds before returning. Then I set these timeouts:

- (in web.config) : `httpRuntime executionTimeout="120"`
- (in global.asax Application_Start) : `Server.ScriptTimeout = 120`
- In IIS (7.5) Manager, I went to the site > Advanced Settings > Connection Limits, and set Connection Time-out to 120

I am not able to get this page to timeout. It successfully returns after 200 seconds without timing out at 120 seconds. I even tried using curl (disabling tcp keepalive) to take the browser out of the picture: `curl --no-keepalive mysiteurl`

Answer (score 2):

First starting with what you already tried:

**executionTimeOut=120** means when some operation is running on server and its takes more than 120 seconds to complete then that operation would time out, similar is the case for Server.ScriptTimeout. **Connection Time Out** specifies the time in which if a connection is not established the connection error would be returned.

That means the above error (execution time out) wouldn't happen unless a synchronous process takes over 2 minutes, or a ServerSide script runs for over 2 minutes, or the connection is not established.

**What you can use.**
I believe you should only be concerned with the session time out if you want the pages to time out in specified time. The other timeouts that you mentioned would work as expected, you can rely on them (refer [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2012/06/21/how-to-troubleshoot-httpexception-request-timed-out-asp-net-4-0-64-bit.aspx) if you want to test if the things are working or not).

If you are performing some db operations then you should consider altering you connection time out for db connection.

Comment: Shashank, I can't seem to get IIS/ASP.NET to timeout on the server side no matter what I do ... and I'm not sure you're correct about IIS > Connection Limits > Connection Timeout (the documentation indicates it applies to already established connections) ... yet +1 for the good link that you provided.

Comment: Dave thanks for marking my answer up. I am confident that I am correct even about connection time out. Here is a link where you can read about it: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/31a2f39c-4d59-4cba-905c-60e7af657e49.mspx?mfr=true               The best example that I can quote in support of this is "you would see a connection time out if you try to upload a substantially large file".

Answer (score 0):

If debug mode is enabled, then these timeouts do not apply:

> This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False. Therefore, if the debug attribute is True, you do not have to set this attribute to a large value in order to avoid application shutdown while you are debugging ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e1f13641(v=vs.100)))